# Proving Eulers Formula

Tags: calculus

Can you prove Eulers' formula e^ix = cos (x) + isin (x), by using the methods of proving two vectors are perpendicular? Taking the velocity vector as e^ix and the position vector cos(x) + i sin (x). I am looking for a mechanics proof of Eulers formula using circular motion (if one exists).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The expressions you mention are (on their face) complex numbers.  How would you think of these as *vectors* (in what vector space would you represent them)?  Using "the methods of proving two vectors are perpendicular" would require a vector space with an *inner product*.  It is unclear what you might think ties any of that to "using circular motion", though again it would require a notion of length (that might be derived from an inner product space).

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain it by solving an ODE:

$$z=\cos x+i\sin x\\
\implies\frac{dz}{dx}=-\sin x+i\cos x=iz\\
\implies z=Ce^{ix}
$$,

where you can solve $C$ to be $1$ since $z(0)=1$.

Comment: @Moo, no it should not

Comment: should not be -iz that is